# Operating System Loader signature found in SecureBoot exclusion database ('dbx'). All bootable devices failed Secure Boot verification

Tags: pop-os, secure-boot

I just downloaded Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (NVIDIA) from the [official website](https://pop.system76.com/), verified the checksum, flashed to a pen drive, and attempted to boot from it.

I forgot to disable Secure Boot as advised on the website, so unsurprisingly, I got an error message. However, the actual contents of the message surprised me:

> Operating System Loader signature found in SecureBoot exclusion database ('dbx'). All bootable devices failed Secure Boot verification.

While I did expect the signature NOT to be found in the signature database, I did not expect to find it in the *exclusion* database.

According to [this website](https://oofhours.com/2021/01/27/uefi-secure-boot-yes-again/):

> dbx, the “forbidden signatures database.” Entries here are typically SHA256 hashes of specific UEFI binaries, i.e. those things that were signed by a certificate in the “db” list but later found to be bad (e.g. having a security vulnerability that compromises the firmware). So this is a “block” list.

How come the signature of the software provided by System76 could have been once valid but since found to be bad?

**Is this a sign of some potential vulnerability in Pop!_OS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mid-2020, a security vulnerability known as [CVE-2020-10713 or BootHole](https://eclypsium.com/2020/07/29/theres-a-hole-in-the-boot/) was found. It affected just about all distributions that used GRUB2 with Secure Boot and had the GRUB `acpi` module included in their Secure Boot-compatible configuration. In its aftermath, security researchers focused more attention on the boot process to find other similar vulnerabilities.

[This led to a group of further vulnerabilities being found, fixed and published in GRUB2 in March 2021.](https://www.debian.org/security/2021-GRUB-UEFI-SecureBoot/) Along with that, Debian had to revoke their old Secure Boot signing key, create new keys and make some changes to their bootloader signing process. Since Ubuntu had a similar Secure Boot infrastructure, [they had to do much the same](https://ubuntu.com/blog/grub2-secure-boot-bypass-2021).

Other distributions that copy their Secure Boot infrastucture from Debian/Ubuntu would have had to do the same, as another part of the security researchers' project was to gather a list of hashes of vulnerable GRUB and `shimx64.efi` versions and revoked Secure Boot signing keys. That list was to be added to the exclusion databases of future Secure Boot firmwares, and eventually distributed as Secure Boot exclusion database updates to existing systems.

In August 9, 2022, Microsoft released a Secure Boot exclusion database update
for Windows that included the exclusions for vulnerable versions of GRUB; a Secure Boot dbx update was also released for the Linux `fwupd`/`fwupdmgr` system. It would seem reasonable to assume that some coordination between Linux distributions and OS vendors was done to ensure all the major OSs were covered.

Now, if Pop!_OS's boot components are now matching the newest exclusion lists, that would indicate they originate from Debian pre-March 2021, or in other words are at level equivalent to Debian 10.9 or older. It would seem that Pop!_OS has skipped some updates.

Granted, they have a recommendation to disable Secure Boot, but since Pop!_OS is based on the corresponding release of Ubuntu, Ubuntu's support of Secure Boot indicates a functional Secure Boot support should have been achievable for Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS too. Perhaps System76 (Pop!_OS's developer) chose to skip getting a Secure Boot certificate from Microsoft? To me, this suggests that Pop!_OS's focus might be more towards style rather than substance.

Basically, the Secure Boot revocation of August 9, 2022 was done to eliminate a false sense of security in case you're still using vulnerable components: your system is no more vulnerable than a system with no Secure Boot in the first place.

If your system is physically secure, there should be no practical way for the attacker to use these vulnerabilities as a way into the system. But if you would rely on Secure Boot to make Evil Maid-type attacks more difficult than your "expected" level of attacker can pull off, then it looks like Pop!_OS might currently be the wrong choice for that use case.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!